# Set Theory Axiomatics

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, axioms

Thinking about Modal Logic made me wonder about Euclidean relations in general, and how they might show up in other areas of math, like Set Theory. I began to think of some examples of Euclidean relations between familiar sets:

1. $\emptyset \in$ {$\emptyset$}, $\emptyset$ $\in$ {$\emptyset$, {$\emptyset$}}, {$\emptyset$} $\in$ {$\emptyset$, {$\emptyset$}},

So, I began to wonder for which sets does this property hold, and given that, what adding this axiom:

$\forall x \forall y \forall z ((x \in y \land x \in z \land y \not =z) \to (y \in z \lor z \in y))$

does to Set Theory in general, and to specific set theories like ZF(C). Is something like this already forbidden by ZF, like the existence of sets that contain themselves?

Comment: (1) The Axiom you have given is not consistent. (2) The Example you have given can be changed to show that : ∅∈{∅} , ∅ ∈ {∅, {{∅}}} , It will not imply {∅} ∈ {∅, {{∅}}} : We can make more Examples !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axiom is blatantly false, for example consider $x=\varnothing, y=\{\varnothing\}, z=\{\varnothing, 8\}$.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Shinrin-Yoku, your axiom is -as far as usual set theory goes- not true.

---

I'll answer the question:

$$
\begin{split}
\textbf{Is something like this already forbidden by ZF,}\\
\textbf{like the existence of sets that contain themselves?}
\end{split}$$

There is; the [Axiom of Regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#Elementary_implications_of_regularity) guarantees no set is a member of itself.